# How to get two different username's from joining two tables in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to display data on table where `createdBy` and `updatedBy` properties display two different usernames taken from the `Users` table.

This is what I got so far:

```
IQueryable<Services> result;

result = (from u in _appContext.Users
          join s in _appContext.Services
                 on u.Id equals s.UpdatedBy
          select new Services
                     {
                         Id = s.Id,
                         CreatedBy = u.UserName, // this should display: admin
                         CreatedDate = s.CreatedDate,
                         UpdatedBy = u.UserName, // this should display: user
                         IsActive = s.IsActive,
                         UpdatedDate = s.UpdatedDate  
                     }).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);
```

By this I get displayed the same (incorrect) username on both `createdBy` & `updatedBy`. In the database, these two properties have the correct `userId` stored.

How do I fix this? Sorry if I'm not clear with my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse your from/join then add a second join:

```
var result = from s in _appContext.Services
  join cu in _appContext.Users on cu.Id equals s.CreatedBy
  join uu in _appContext.Users on uu.Id equals s.UpdatedBy
  
select new Services 
{
  Id = s.Id,
  CreatedBy = cu.UserName,
  CreatedDate = s.CreatedDate,
  UpdatedBy = uu.UserName,
  IsActive = s.IsActive,
  UpdatedDate = s.UpdatedDate  
});
```

Note: I've not tested this with real data.

Comment: Thank you! I tried something about the same haha but gave up too soon. This worked perfectly!